# Get the text controler value from the client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

someone telll me what is wrong thid code.I coulnt reach the textPlaka value ,
I can get the values id and theString  but not Plaka.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var id = "55";
            var theString = "asdf";
            var Plaka = document.getElementById('<%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>').value; 





            $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
                'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
                'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script': 'Upload.ashx',
                'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
                'folder': 'upload',
                'multi': true,
                'method'   : 'post',
                'buttonText': 'RESIM SEC',
                'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
                'auto': false,
                'formData': { 'id': id,'foo': theString ,'Plaka':Plaka},
                onAllComplete: function (event, data) {

                }

            });
        });
```

and here is the controler

```
  <ext:TextField ID="txtPlaka" runat="server" FieldLabel="Plaka" Flex="1" AllowBlank="false">
                        </ext:TextField>
```

thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the value of `var Plaka` at `ready()` function. ie, when the page loads.
If there is no value when the page loads you can't get any value!

Also, you are using a control (`ext:TextField`). Please look how its HTML being rendered. Use F12 in Google Chrome to Inspect Element.

UPDATE:

Suppose you have a submit button and its id is btnSubmit
Try something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var id = "55";




$("#btnMusteriEkle").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
        var theString = "asdf";
        var Plaka = document.getElementById('<%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>').value;
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").uploadify({
            'uploader': 'Upload.ashx',
            'swf': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'folder': 'upload',
            'multi': true,
            'method'   : 'post',
            'buttonText': 'RESIM SEC',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.jpeg',
            'auto': false,
            'formData': { 'id': id,'foo': theString ,'Plaka':Plaka},
            onAllComplete: function (event, data) {

            }

        });
       });
    });
```

You will be getting the values fro handler I suppose. You can use

```
string PlakaValue=context.Request.Form["Plaka"];
```

Comment: so should I remove $(document).ready(function () { this part?

Comment: No, you must not. It depends on your usage. When the user will input data into textBox? When do you want to make this upload?

Comment: so how can I achiave that

Comment: yes ,Subin,also I have submit button something like this, <ext:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnMusteriEkle" Text="Yeni müşteri ekle">
                       <Listeners>
                       <Click Handler="if(#{FormPanel1}.isValid()){javascript:$('#FileUpload1').uploadify('upload','*')}"></Click>
                       </Listeners>//listeners render as javascript 
                        </ext:Button>

Comment: it seesm diffucult apply your solition here .<Click Handler="if(#{FormPanel1}.isValid()){javascript:$('#FileUpload1').uploadify('upl‌​oad','*')}"></Click> </Listeners>

Comment: You simply use an asp button with id `btnMusteriEkle`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38528/discussion-between-user2460637-and-subin-jacob)

Comment: dear friend I tryied what u said but seems doent work

Comment: this part(var Plaka ) still get the null value,firebug says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: It says that you are not getting the element with this id (`txtPlaka.ClientID`).This happens when no element with the ID specified is not found. Please check the source of your html after rendering the page into browser

Comment: I am creattting dynamically usercontrol and load ascx file and define $(document).ready(function () { these inside it .does it effect the running script.thank you ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simplify your code to the following:

**Example**

```
// Existing
// var Plaka = document.getElementById('<%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>').value; 

// Revised
var Plaka = <%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>.getValue();
```

If you are calling that code during the initial page load, the `txtPlaka` TextField may not have a value set.

You could also get the `txtPlaka` value when you make the call to `uploadify`.

**Example**

```
// Existing
// 'formData': { 'id': id,'foo': theString ,'Plaka':Plaka},

// Revised
'formData': { 'id': id,'foo': theString ,'Plaka':<%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>.getValue()},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I applyed the second example()I got the null value of the Plaka!?how can I solve this.thank ou again

Comment: If you are calling that code during the initial page load, the txtPlaka TextField may not have a value set.*Yes I am doing this

Comment: If you are calling txtPlaka during the initial page load, then it will not return a value. You would have to call later in a separate function, maybe something similar to what @Subin Jacob provided above. But do not use the .getElementById function. Just replace that line with var Plaka = <%= txtPlaka.ClientID %>.getValue();